# How many tokens are there in below statements?

Tags: compiler-construction, token

If I have statements like :

```
int 1xab; //statement 1
int 1 ;   //statement 2
```

If I go for calculating the number of tokens in it , then according to me , no of tokens in statement 1 is 4 and in statement 2 is 3 .

**For statement 1**:

- I have 1 as the token for integer literal and xab as the token for an
  identifier .

**For statement 2**.

- I have 1 as the token for integer literal .

Is The approach correct ?

Comment: If you're constructing a compiler it's up to you to define tokens.

Comment: +1 to @klutt but I'd point out that in case #1 it is ambiguous whether `1xab` is A) A valid identifier, B) An invalid identifier or C) Two tokens. as you control the token demarcation logic it is suggested not to create obfuscated syntax

Answer (score 1):

There is no "correct" or "incorrect" here unless you are working to the specification of a particular language. In the abstract, either answer is possible (as are others) and different possibilities exist in different languages.

- In Python and a great number of other languages, `1xab` is two tokens. The initial integer is matched using the maximal munch rule, and then `xab` is left to be parsed as a second token. In most of these languages, there is no syntactic construct where an identifier can follow a token, so a syntax error will be triggered anyway and the distinction is academic.
- In C and C++, integer literals can be suffixed by alphabetic markers. (For example, 1llu is an unsigned `long long` integer literal.) The designers of C choose to allow for possible extensions to this lexical syntax, so any string of alphanumeric characters starting with a digit is considered a "pp-number". [Note 1]

So if you are implementing a processor for an existing language, you need to consult the specification of that language. If you are designing your own language, you can choose whichever definition of token you find more convenient.

---

#### Notes

1. "Pp-numbers" can also contain decimal points (<kbd>.</kbd>) and exponents (<kbd>E+</kbd>), and can start with a decimal point followed by a digit. So it's a bit more complicated than that. Recent C++ versions also allow the use of <kbd>'</kbd> as a grouping symbol making it easier to write large integers in a readable way.

   For clarity, here is the C lexical grammar for preprocessing numbers (§6.4.8 of the C11 standard):

   ```
   pp-number:
       digit
       . digit
       pp-number digit
       pp-number identifier-nondigit
       pp-number e sign
       pp-number E sign
       pp-number p sign
       pp-number P sign
       pp-number .
   sign: one of
       + -
   digit: one of
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   ```

   An `identifier-non-digit` is a letter (only those in the [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) subset, i.e. <kbd>a</kbd> to <kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> to <kbd>Z</kbd>), a <kbd>_</kbd> underscore, a unicode escape ("universal character name") provided it is in a list of valid codepoints, or "other implementation-defined characters".

Comment: But when we talk about longest sequence of matching characters , if I have seen 1 , then If I enter into the automata of the integer constant , then If I see xab , then it is something else ("others") in the automata defined , so why can't this be a valid token in C as well ?

Comment: @radhika: simply because of the way the "pp-number" token is defined by the language. Like most languages, C depends on the longest match rule, and `1xab` is the longest match for a pp-number.

Comment: If I talk about C language , as you said if xab comes ,since it is an invalid suffix , so we report it as lexical error but then why can't we  enter into the final state of the DFA which has just digits as it's input , we can even have the DFA for it without adding any suffix to it so in that case 1 would be a token and xab would be another token

Comment: @radhika: That would have been possible, but the language designers decided not to. That was their right :) Their reasoning was that someday they might want to make `x` a valid suffix, in which case any old program which relied on `1xab` being precisely the tokens `1` and `xab` would suddenly have different behaviour. In fact, in C++ integers can be suffixed with *any* identifier, allowing the possibility to use numbers which include a measure unit (`1_km`; the underscore is not required for suffixes defined in the standard library. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).

Comment: when I run it on gcc compiler , it gives invalid suffix "xab" with integer constant , that means integer constant is indeed recognised , but the context does not expect to see "xab" after the constant , so it is a syntax error .

Comment: That's correct. It is definitely a syntax error, rather than being two tokens. Preprocessing tokens which survive the preprocessing phases must be converted to tokens, and 1xab is not a valid token. But it is still a single invalid token. To prove that, try this: `#define xab +2`. Now, if `1xab` were two tokens, it would expand to `1+2`, which is perfectly valid. `1 xab` will expand. But `1xab` will still be an error.

Comment: So if 1 is a valid token , then what will happen to the suffix xab , will the lexical analyzer not go to search for the longest sequence of characters and find this xab analogous to an identifier and generate a token for it ?

Comment: @radhika: the token is `1xab`. That's it. The lexer identifies it as a token according to the lexical grammar I quoted in the answer, and then later it is flagged as an error because it  cannot be converted to a valid integer literal token. Splitting the token at that point is not allowed by the language specification.

Comment: So does splitting of a token occurs only when some delimeter comes ? In short when does the lexical analyser starts comparing the next sequence of characters with a pattern after it has generated a token and the sequence of the characters for which it is searching is not separated with any delimeter from the recent token generated .

Comment: @radhika: C uses the usual longest-match algorithm with no exceptions. (In C++ there are a couple of minor exceptions.) What you are refusing to understand is the patterns it uses to define its numeric tokens. I honestly don't know how to explain this any more. Did you even look at the grammar I pasted? What about it do you not understand?

Comment: I understood your point , "xab" is others in the DFA given in below image .

Comment: I understood your point , "xab" is others in the DFA given in this image https://cs.nyu.edu/~gottlieb/courses/2000s/2007-08-fall/compilers/lectures/diagrams/trans-dia-num.png                                     So when it reads 1 , it goes to state 13 and when it sees x , it reaches final state 20 and return the token 1 . Now since xab is not a token , so in which phase do we come to know that xab is an invalid suffix of 1 (integer constant )

Comment: So just last query , what happens with the others stated in the image in above comment . For instance , I have 5<3 , Now for the DFA of < , when it sees 3 , it comes under others , it accepts only < , Now , it will generate token for < operator but it has seen 3 as well , so will it now start its lexical analysis again and find this 3 analogous to an integer constant

Comment: so basically I am a bit confused with what happens with this others portion , since if in the example 1xab , xab is ignored , since it comes under others portion then even 3 should be ignored as it is the portion of others in the DFA for < operator .                                                https://cs.nyu.edu/~gottlieb/courses/2000s/2007-08-fall/compilers/lectures/diagrams/trans-dia-relop.png

Comment: This is my last query , I just need a small clarification of others , since in case of xab , you are saying token will not be generated and in one case of 3 , a token will be generated as an integer constant .

Comment: @Radhika: I am talking specifically about the C language. You are talking about a simplified language used in a compilers course, which has a different lexical structure, a different syntax, and probably different semantics. You cannot use the diagrams from those course notes to understand lexical analysis of C. If you try, you will end up being confused. If you think there is a single lexical structure defined by a law of the universe, this would be a good time to rethink. Every language has its own tokens and there is no right or wrong way to define them.